# SkipDuplicates not avaiable in nuget 5.0.2

Tags: c#, nuget

I want to push a package with nuget push and want to skip duplicate Versions.
But the options seems to be not avaiable, but the documentation say it has to be.
Can anyone help?

I read this https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/nuget/tools/cli-ref-push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's available from NuGet 5.1. I'll ask the developer to update the docs.